# SeeTest Junit simple automation

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, junit4, seetest

I'm trying to create a simple Junit test with SeeTest, after reading this [tutorial](http://experitest.com/studio/help3/WebHelp/index.htm#page=Export_Code_to_JUnit.htm),
on eclipse with Junit4.

1. I recorded some actions in SeeTest and saved it.
2. Took the exported code as is.
3. Opened a new Android test project + and pasted the code from SeeTest (3).
4. Run as Android Junit test.

This is the console output:

```
[2013-05-27 12:13:30 - MY_APP_TEST] Android Launch!
[2013-05-27 12:13:30 - MY_APP_TEST] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-27 12:13:30 - MY_APP_TEST] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2013-05-27 12:13:30 - MY_APP_TEST] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-05-27 12:13:30 - MY_APP_TEST] Project dependency found, installing: MY_APP
[2013-05-27 12:13:31 - MY_APP] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-05-27 12:13:31 - MY_APP_TEST] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on 3134A2179BDA00EC
[2013-05-27 12:13:31 - MY_APP_TEST] Failed to launch test
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong and how can I monitor or debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the JUnit system out.
Also the error.log located under %appdata%\seetest will help.
Thanks,

Comment: Right. The JUnit test running by SeeTest are been executed outside of the device.